# SQL Deadlock question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-deadlocks

Is it possible in relational databases for these two statements to deadlock?  I'm trying to simplify my question and example -- please just assume that these selects, which I think would normally only require sharable read-locking, now require exclusive read locks:

```
Concurrent Connection 1:
SELECT {...}
FROM A 
JOIN B ON {...}

Concurrent Connection 2:
SELECT {...}
FROM B 
JOIN A ON {...}
```

That is, does the ordering of the joins matter?  Are single statements in SQL atomic?  Is A locked first and then B in the first statement and B locked first and then A in the second statement?

I think not - My gut tells me that two single statements like this cannot deadlock, no matter how complex.  I believe that a statement is analyzed as a whole and that the resources requiring locking are locked using some deterministic global order (i.e. alphabetically).  But I need more than a gut feeling on this - I can't think of a way to prove it and I can't find it documented.

I'm interested in MS SQL 2005, but I don't think the question is implementation specific.

Secondarily: As it relates to MS SQL, I'd also want to know that Common Table Expressions also have this guarantee - that CTEs are mostly a syntactic benefit (+recursion), consolidated into a traditional single statement by the engine.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are actually doing rather than simplifying it with some hypothetical example? What isolation level are you using? What is the nature of the actual queries - are they selects or something different?

Comment: Interesting question. I share your gut feeling, but I don't have any evidence. Your question might be clearer if you asked for update locks on both tables in each query.

Comment: IMHO, this question is implementation specific. For example, in Oracle, readers do not block writers (or even other readers), so two SELECT's would never result in a deadlock (unless they were SELECT .. FOR UPDATE's). Not entirely sure about MSSQL's locking implementation though

Comment: I don't think this is so hypothetical as it is just simplified to clear out irrelevant details.  When building apps we often have a variety of entities and we can run into deadlocks easily if you don't enter your locks in the same order every time (database or otherwise).  Sometimes you want to look up the customer and their orders by customer ID, sometimes you need the order and the customer by order number.

Comment: @bhangm - For SQL Server depends on the tranasction isolation level. There is snapshot isolation where readers read previous committed versions of rows rather than being blocked by writers.

Comment: This fellow here is obviously getting them...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239641/best-isolation-level-to-avoid-deadlocks-using-an-update-sentence-in-sql-server-2

Comment: I'm really talking about READ COMMITTED but this isn't a question about isolation levels, although it wouldn't be applicable in READ UNCOMMITTED, SNAPSHOT, or SERIALIZABLE, for example.

Comment: One possibility: Though it requires one additional query, in complex apps, having a few XLOCKRootResourceByX stored procedures helps simplify the application logic. XLockCustomerByID, XLOCKCustomerByOrderNum for example. If I call this at the front of each transaction, then I know I've put a fence around my Customer and it's related data. The Orders don't have to be XLOCKed locked as long as I always synchronize by Customer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SELECTs cannot deadlock with other SELECT, because they only acquire shared locks. You say that we should consider that these SELECTs now 'require exclusive read locks', but this is not possible for us to consider because 1) there is no such thing as an `exlusive read lock` and 2) reads don't acquire exclusive locks.

But you do pose a more general question, whether simple statements can deadlock. The answer is a definite, resounding **YES**. Locks are acquired at execution, not analyzed upfront and sorted then acquired in some order. It would be impossible for the engine to know upfront the needed locks because they depend on the actual data in on-disk, and to read the data the engine needs to ... lock the data.

Deadlocks between simple statements (SELECt vs. UPDATE or SELECT vs. DELETE) due to different index access order are quite common and very easy to investigate, diagnose and fix. But note that there is *always* a write operation involved, as reads cannot block each other. For this discussion, adding a UPDLOCK or XLOCK hint to a SELECT should be considered a write. You don't even need a JOIN, a secondary index may well introduce the access order problem leading to deadlock, see [Read/Write Deadlock](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/).

And finally, writing `SELECT FROM A JOIN B` or writing `SELECT FROM B JOIN A` is completely irrelevant. The query optimizer is free to rearrange the access order as it sees fit, the actual text of the query does not impose the order of execution in any way.

**Updated**

> How then can we construct a general
>   strategy toward a READ COMMITTED
>   "multiple entity" database that
>   doesn't deadlock?

I'm afraid there is no cookie-cutter recipe. The solution will depend from case to case. Ultimately, in database applications deadlocks are a fact of life. I understand this may sound absurd, as in 'we landed on the Moon but we can't write a correct database application', but there are strong factors at play which pretty much guarantee that applications will eventually encounter deadlocks. Lucky deadlocks are *the* easiest to deal with errors, simple read again the state, apply the logic, re-write the new state. Now that being said, there are some good practices that can dramatically reduce the frequency of deadlocks, down to the point they are all but vanished:

- Try to have a consistent access pattern for *Writes*. Have clearly defined rules stating things such as 'a transaction shall always tables in this order: `Customers` -> `OrderHeaders` -> `OrderLines`.' Note that the order has to be obeyed inside a *transaction*.  Basically, rank **all** tables in your schema and specify that all updates must occur in ranking order. This eventually boils down to code discipline of the individual contributor writing the code, as it has to ensure it writes is update sin the proper order inside a transaction.
- Reduce the *duration* of writes. The usual wisdom goes as this: at the beginning of the transaction do all the reads (read the existing state), then process the logic and compute new values, then write all updates at the end of transaction. Avoid a pattern like 'read->write->logic->read->write', instead do 'read->read->logic->write->write'. Of course, the true craftsmanship consist in how to deal with actual, real, individual cases when apparently one *must* have to do writes mid-transaction. A special note here must be said about a specific type of transaction: those driven by a queue, which by very definition start their activity by dequeueing  (= a write) from the queue. These applications were always notoriously difficult to write and prone to errors (specially deadlocks), luckily there are ways to do it, see [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).
- Reduce the amount of reads. Table scans are *the* most prevalent cause of deadlocks. Proper indexing will not only eliminate the deadlocks, but may also boost performance in the process.
- [Snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28VS.80%29.aspx). This is the closest thing you'll get to a free lunch in regard to avoiding deadlocks. I intentionally put it last, because it may *mask* other problems (like improper indexing) instead of fixing them.

Trying to solve this problem with a `LockCustomerByXXX` approach I'm afraid doesn't work. Pessimistic locking doesn't scale. [Optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx) updates are *the* way to go if you want to have any sort of decent performance.

Comment: Some databases allow the creation of triggers on SELECT.  If the trigger did an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE, then probably those queries could deadlock.

Also, if A or B were views or stored-procedures instead of raw tables, it might be possible for the underlying logic of the views/stored-procs to contain UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE.

Admittedly, both of these possibilities are quite esoteric!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the thoughtful response.  I'm having trouble understanding how any practical application can function deadlock-free in such an environment.  How then can we construct a general strategy toward a READ COMMITTED "multiple entity" database that doesn't deadlock?  Please consider the customer&orders-by-customer-id/order&customer-by-order-num comments on the original question.  Is it possible to safely acquire a lock on the customer regardless of the "entry point" (customer id/order num)?

Comment: Without retrying, that is.  I just want each transaction to wait it's turn, synchronized by some overall locking strategy such as (XLOCKCustomerByID, XLOCKCustomerByOrderNumber, XLOCKCustomersByOrderDate how can I guarantee that these statements don't deadlock, no dirty reads, and allowing concurrent transactions for Customers and Orders that are not related (ignore proximity locks like page locks).  Once an XLOCKCustomerBy* statement finished, the data would be reserved for the transaction, so the overall problem has been reduced to the correct implementation of XLOCKCustomerBy*.

Comment: I'd put this in a new question but I there's too much background really, I can't figure out how to state the problem more simply.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are correct: the SQL engine figures out what it will need to do (probably as it parses the query), locks all required resources, executes the query, and then unlocks them.

Answer (score 0):

Reads won't deadlock each other. You must have some write going on as well.

You can do things to reduce the number of deadlocks. For example, insert only at the end of a clustered index on platforms that support row locking and avoid updating records. Ah hah, now Facebook's UI makes more sense.

It's sometimes easier to handle the deadlocks than avoid them. The server will fail and report back, and you can retry.

Comment: I would have specified the XLOCK hint in the actual statements, but I thought XLOCK was MS specific.